# Creating objects with late binding causes ActiveX runtime error 429 depending on file folder location

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, activex

I have come across a strange behavior in Excel VBA when creating objects using late binding.

**System information:**

- Windows 10 Enterprise Version: 1803
- Office 365 MSO (16.0.11126.20192)32 bit

**Problem description:**

I have an empty Excel sheet with a macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ob As Object
    Set ob = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub
```

Running this macro gives me

> Run time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Depending on the folder where I store the macro enabled Excel file.

**Folders where I can run the macro without errors**

- my one drive folder: C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive - MY Company Name\
- all the subfolders inside this one.

**Folders where errors occurs**

- C:\Users\myusername\
- C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\
- Shared network location ex: \xpto\xpto1\
- C:\Temp\
- C:\Q\ folder I created where I tried to mimic the same access rights as in the OneDrive folder where the macro works.

**If I use early binding with the correct references the problem is not there anymore!**

I tried following some steps in: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications.

Comment: Could this be about trusted folders? Either the one holding the file or the one holding the DLL?

Comment: Seems like a bug in Windows. This link says that *This error does not occur on all computers*.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications
Can you try your code on another computer? On mine it works ok (Win 7, 64, Office 2016)

Comment: I will try support directly from Microsoft, let's see what they answer.

Comment: After some additional discussion's with my company IT dptm, we found the problem, this is related to the AV software used.

My Documents is the only location where the scripts can be run.

Thanks for the help anyway.